# How to push modal in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want to push multiples times the same modal, but when i run navigation.push, the modal is not a modal.

It's possible to use navigation.push to show a modal ?

UPDATE:
I have set the animationEnabled to false, so modal didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You can have modals in navigation **stacks**. For the screens to show up as modal, they need to be configured as such. So where you create your navigation stack, add `presentation: "modal"` to the `screenOptions`.

From the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/):

```
function RootStackScreen() {
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator>
      <RootStack.Group>
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </RootStack.Group>
      <RootStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </RootStack.Group>
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

If you have multiple screens configured as modal, you should be able to push them above each other.

Comment: Hello and thank you but i want to use navigation.push and modal screen but it’s. Doesn’t work, do you have an idea why ?